# How to get Azure EventHub data using node js

Tags: node.js, azure, npm, azure-eventhub

I am a beginner in **Microsoft event hub**. I am successfully sending data to `eventHub` using node js([refrence](http://hypernephelist.com/2014/09/16/sending-data-to-azure-event-hubs-from-nodejs.html)).

How to receive and display the data from event hub? Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot receive messages using the Azure Event Hub REST APÎ.  You can only receive using AMQP 1.0.

Your best option is to look for an AMQP npm package.  A quick search also lead me to this: https://github.com/noodlefrenzy/node-amqp10

Comment: Hey, I'm the (co-)author of https://github.com/noodlefrenzy/node-amqp10 and I use it to speak to Event Hubs all the time (send and receive). There's an example in the examples/ directory, and we just released 2.1.0, so we're actively maintaining it.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the official JavaScript SDK for Azure Event Hubs, [@azure/event-hubs](http://npmjs.com/package/@azure/event-hubs).